# BG 44K Fuel system cleaner?

Tags: fuel-system

What's the proper way of using the product? With full or half tank of gas?
Is it recommended to do motor oil change after the cleaner? Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 4):

To utilize BG44K, put the entire can in your fuel tank just prior to fill-up at the gas pump. This will ensure the product is completely mixed with your fuel. You should use at a ratio of one can to an entire fuel tank (for passenger car/truck). If using it in a motorcycle or some other small engines, you will need to decrease the amount used, but figure about one can per 15-18 US gallons.

BG44K is a *fuel* treatment. It should be used in the gas tank. BG has other products which can be used to treat the [oil](http://www.bgprod.com/catalog/engine/bg-moa/#bg-product-1). There is no need to change the oil or filter when using BG44K by itself. If you get other treatments, it may be required.

I understand the BG44K can has very little instruction on it. The [BG website](http://www.bgprod.com/catalog/gasoline-fuel-system/bg-44k-fuel-system-cleaner/#bg-product-1) has even less. I am going to assume it is this way because BG44K can only be purchased through a licensed dealer, which is usually a maintenance garage. You will not (as of this post) find it at WalMart, Target, or other such stores. I have seen it for purchase on eBay, though.

Answer (score 2):

[The product page](http://www.bgprod.com/catalog/gasoline-fuel-system/bg-44k-fuel-system-cleaner/#bg-product-1) describes the product as follows:

> Just one can of BG 44K® in your fuel tank can boost your car’s
>   performance...

As it is spring, I'm assuming this stuff is supposed to end up in a bike. I have never used it, or even know if it's available in my country, but why not scale it down to the corresponding ratio for your tank volume? I cant find any instruction, but should they not be printed on the bottle it's that important?

Answer (score 1):

1-can treats up to 20 gallons. The can is 11 oz. which works out to .55 oz. per gallon.  Manufacturer recommends adding it to a full tank and then refueling when you get down to a half tank.  This keeps the treatment in the fuel as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Search for BG44K found on Amazon and Ebay for less than $17, free shipping.  But there's more to cleaning fuel system/injectors than just adding a can of this stuff, better know what you're doing if you're a DIYselfer- talk to a mechanic first!

Comment: I don't believe this information answered the question.